# Create python dictionary by enumerate function

Tags: python

I am looking for a simpler way to create this python dictionary. May I know if enumerate function can help?

```
a_dict = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2, ....}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `enumerate` you can use a [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) and [`string.ascii_lowercasewithin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) within `dict` :

```
>>> import string
>>> dict((j,i) for i,j in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase))
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3, 'g': 6, 'f': 5, 'i': 8, 'h': 7, 'k': 10, 'j': 9, 'm': 12, 'l': 11, 'o': 14, 'n': 13, 'q': 16, 'p': 15, 's': 18, 'r': 17, 'u': 20, 't': 19, 'w': 22, 'v': 21, 'y': 24, 'x': 23, 'z': 25}
```

As `enumerate` returns tuples in format `(index,element)` you can loop over it and just change the indices with element then convert it to dict.

Answer (score 2):

you may simply use `string.ascii_lowercase` which is string of all lowercase characters, then you `zip` the lowercase letters and list of number ranging from `0` to `len(string.ascii_lowercase)` and then convert them to `dict`.

However you may want to use some other set of alphabet as `string.ascii_letters`, `string.ascii_uppercase` , `string.letters`, `string.punctuation`, etc.

You can easily filter the keys that you want in your dictionary either by concatenating the above mentioned strings as `string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase` would give us a string containing first the 26 lowercase alphabets and then 26 uppercase alphabets, you may also apply slicing methods to get desired set of characters, like `string.ascii_lowercase[0:15]` would give you `"abcdefghijklmn"`

```
import string

alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase
print dict(zip(alphabets, range(len(alphabets))))
>>> {'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3, 'g': 6, 'f': 5, 'i': 8, 'h': 7, 'k': 10, 'j': 9, 'm': 12, 'l': 11, 'o': 14, 'n': 13, 'q': 16, 'p': 15, 's': 18, 'r': 17, 'u': 20, 't': 19, 'w': 22, 'v': 21, 'y': 24, 'x': 23, 'z': 25}
```

Comment: Why not  `range(26)`?

Comment: @Kasra the OP may be sometimes doesn't want exactly 26 characters, may be he just want a strip from `[0:15]`, or may be want both upper and lowercase characters.

Comment: Since you passed `ascii_lowercase` you need to pass 26 otherwise you cal mention that;)

Answer (score 2):

I would use an infinite number generator like `itertools.count` to generate numbers from 0. Then zip the ascii characters with count and create the tuples needed for the dictionary generation.

```
>>> from itertools import count, izip
>>> import string
>>> 
>>> dict(izip(string.ascii_lowercase, count()))
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3, 'g': 6, 'f': 5, 'i': 8, 'h': 7, 'k': 10, 'j': 9, 'm': 12, 'l': 11, 'o': 14, 'n': 13, 'q': 16, 'p': 15, 's': 18, 'r': 17, 'u': 20, 't': 19, 'w': 22, 'v': 21, 'y': 24, 'x': 23, 'z': 25}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `....` means you want the alphabet:

```
{chr(i+97): i for i in range(26)}
```

Comment: Since OP has asked using enumerate you are bound to use it :P

Comment: Well, OP also said *"I am looking for a simpler way to create this python dictionary."*, which this is. I'm responding to that part.